# Azure App won't start and getting a HTTP 500 error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, blazor, blazor-server-side, azure-appservice

So I'm currently running a Blazor .NET Core server side App on Azure App Services in a linux based config, the below is my environment

```
System info
System up time: 5.05:06:19.3920000
OS version: Unix 4.15.0.112
64 bit system: True
64 bit process: True
Processor count: 1
Short instance id: bdcba9
CLR version: 4.0.30319.42000
System directory:
Current working directory: /opt/Kudu
IIS command line: /opt/Kudu/Kudu.Services.Web.dll
```

It was all running fine yesterday but as of today when I made a minor change to some text and did a re-publish. And suddenly I am now getting a HTTP 500 error with this in the kudu log stream. You can see it crashing when trying to get a cultureinfo with what I presume is an incorrect parameter (GetMethodFromHandle perhaps) Locally its all running fine with no issues and hitting no exceptions even with it set to hit everything/all exception types. There is also nowhere in my app I set CultureInfo or play around with Locale.

```
2020-09-12T12:07:40.245382681Z: [INFO]  [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
2020-09-12T12:07:40.245431982Z: [INFO]        An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
2020-09-12T12:07:40.247771813Z: [INFO]  System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported. (Parameter 'name')
2020-09-12T12:07:40.247802114Z: [INFO]  ethodFromHandle is an invalid culture identifier.
2020-09-12T12:07:40.247876715Z: [INFO]     at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String name)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.247892415Z: [INFO]     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetLocale()
2020-09-12T12:07:40.247937615Z: [INFO]     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetName(Boolean copiedName)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.247952516Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ServerComponentSerializer.CreateSerializedServerComponent(ServerComponentInvocationSequence invocationId, Type rootComponent, ParameterView parameters)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.247999016Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.NonPrerenderedServerComponent(HttpContext context, ServerComponentInvocationSequence invocationId, Type type, ParameterView parametersCollection)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.248015117Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(ViewContext viewContext, Type componentType, RenderMode renderMode, Object parameters)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.248055617Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ComponentTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.248079317Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, Int32 i, Int32 count)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.248117818Z: [INFO]     at BHub.Pages.Pages__Host.<ExecuteAsync>b__15_1() in D:\Sites\BHub\BHub\Pages\_Host.cshtml:line 29
2020-09-12T12:07:40.249937843Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
2020-09-12T12:07:40.249974943Z: [INFO]     at BHub.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync() in D:\Sites\BHub\BHub\Pages\_Host.cshtml:line 5
2020-09-12T12:07:40.250014644Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.267442179Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.267524481Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.267669083Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.267711783Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
2020-09-12T12:07:40.267807784Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
```

I am not quite sure what's causing this and wondering if anyone else has had anything similar or could shed some light. I understand it gets the culture from the OS but there's been no changes on my end and it was working previously. I'm not sure what I can try as locally it's fine, I'm sort of leaning towards a problem in a Azure App/Linux config but.. hmph

Comment: So where/how do you set a culture? Is it in your code (setting up Loacaliztion perhaps)?

Comment: I don't set any cultures or use locale anywhere in my code. I presume the code is just trying to get it from the OS

Comment: Yes, it gets it from the OS (or CLR). But why, and which culture?  What language(s) do you have in your Browser?

Comment: My browser (chrome) is in English, UK. I'm unsure what region my linux server is on azure, should be en-gb or en-us but I guess that's something I'll check if I can?

Comment: I'm not sure about Linux, I have ran into something similar with regional cultures on Windows, not everything was installed.

Comment: With the stack trace showing it's trying to pass a method's name in the culture name parameter, looks definitely fishy to me.

Comment: Yes, but there is an M missing, is that a typo on your side?  And can you post line 5 from _Host.cshtml, probably the TagHelpers.

Comment: Sure, `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`. And yes, that is pasted directly from the log so looks like its been truncated somehow

Comment: You may have stumbled on a bug. First make sure everything is uptodate, RuntimeAssembly.GetLocale() dives into an unmanaged DLL. So clear out your folders and do a re-deploy.

Comment: CLR version: 4.0 seem a bit odd, but I don't know what you should see. Do you deploy as self-contained?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221380/discussion-between-benjay-uk-and-henk-holterman).

Comment: No, I don't do chat. And nobody ever reads that.

Comment: I deploy as framework-dependent although I've tried deploying as self-contained to no avail. Same issue.

Comment: I think you should report this one on GitHub. Make sure to mention the version(s).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time & help. Much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332304/why-do-i-get-culture-is-not-supported-and-what-if-anything-should-i-do-abou

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't necessarily call this a solution but I basically noticed that when I was deploying it wasn't restarting the web server after pushing the files like it should do. I removed and re-added this app to the deployment list to get it to start doing this again and voila. It now restarts after deployment and seems to work again.

```
Updating file (bhublive\System.Runtime.Caching.dll).
Updating file (bhublive\web.config).
Publish Succeeded.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

> ```
> Waiting for Web App to be ready...
> Restarting the Web App...
> Successfully restarted Web App.
> ```

```
Web App is ready.
```

Comment: It is an answer. You were running on corrupted or out-of-sync files before.