# .NET Chinese CultureInfo "zh" does not exist?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, chinese-locale

I'm using .NET 3.5 and running the following code:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("zh"); // Throws ArgumentException
```

I got the string "zh" from an xml:lang attribute. I don't understand why an exception is thrown, because for instance "de" (wich is parent for "de-DE") is working fine. The culture "zh-CN" does work, but thats nothing that I can use.

**Edit:**
It works on .NET 4.5.1 (thanks to xanatos) - so even if the MSDN page explains that Chinese is an exception, the behaviour is different in newer .NET versions.

Comment: There is no culture as only `zh` in .NET Framework. You can check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488%28v=cs.20%29.aspx

Comment: @SonerGönül Under .NET 4.5 it works :-)

Comment: @SonerGönül That is *Commerce Server 2002*

Comment: CultureInfo identifies the culture names from this list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx

Comment: @xanatos Right, it seems as `NeutralCultures` as a type :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET 3.5 "zh" does not work, use "zh-Hans" or "zh-Hant" instead. Didn't find a better solution. Or switch to .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 4):

There is a small note on the [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) page:

> There are two culture names that contradict this rule. The cultures Chinese (Simplified), named zh-Hans, and Chinese (Traditional), named zh-Hant, are neutral cultures. The culture names represent the current standard and should be used unless you have a reason for using the older names zh-CHS and zh-CHT.

So you could try `zh-Hans` or `zh-Hant`

And/or you could see [What cultures are supported by the CultureInfo class in .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282411/what-cultures-are-supported-by-the-cultureinfo-class-in-net-3-5)

The accepted answer says:

> Unfortunately, it is OS dependent. Check here for default language support per OS.

Comment: Its not the answer, it's not OS depended but .NET version dependent.